# Stationary time series having unusual ACF and PACF plots

Tags: time-series, stationarity, acf-pacf

I'm analysing a highly stationary time series and while plotting ACF and PACF I noticed a strange bump at a later lag very close to the 0.5 threshold level. Does it affect the AR degree=2 and AM degree =1 in the ARIMA model?

Results of Dickey-Fuller test

`Test Statistic                -6.218402e+00` 
`p-val                          5.296241e-08` 
`#Lags Used                     2.000000e+00` 
`Number of Observations Used    4.380000e+02` 
`Critical Value 1%             -3.445368e+00` 
`Critical Value 5%             -2.868161e+00` 
`Critical Value 10%            -2.570297e+00` 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Does it affect the AR degree=2 and AM degree =1 in the ARIMA model?***

If it's daily data, then you should look up for what those lags around 34 could mean (economically, financially, etc), which depends on the nature of your variable. Statistically, it could be a concern, but the type of variable could overcome that. Therefore that bump could be spurious (not a concern).

Besides that, a "true" stationary data shouldn't be almost equal to 1 on the first lag at partial correlation. There may be other issues, like structural breaks, that can cause false positive of a unit root test.